# Format Numberfield in percentages

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

We have a `NumberField` which we want to use for a percentage value and used this:

```
<NumberField source="fee"  options={{ style: 'percent' }} sortable={false} />
```

However, our API sends the value as a string because it is not represented as a float. This seems to break the `NumberField` as the `options` are not picked up and the value is displayed as we receive it in the API response.

Is there a way to change the string `"0.05"` into `5%` in react-admin fields?

Answer (score 3):

`NumberField` uses `Intl.NumberFormat()` to format a number. `Intl.NumberFormat()` accepts 2 inputs: `locales` and `options`. Now look how `Intl.NumberFormat()` works:

```js
const number = "0.05";

// without locales
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat({ style: 'percent' }).format(number)); // result 0,05

// with locales
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { style: 'percent' }).format(number)); // result 5%
```

As you can see, if you don't use `locales`, the output is equal to the input. But if you use `'en-IN'` locales, `Intl.NumberFormat()` returns `5%`.

So you have to modify your code in this way:

```
<NumberField source="fee" locales="en-IN" options={{ style: 'percent' }} sortable={false} />
```

Comment: The explanation makes sense, but it does not change anything when I use it in react-admin. Setting the `locales="en-IN"` for `"0.05"` results in `0.05`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to build a custom field component:

```
const PercentageField = ({source}) => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    const absoluteValue = get(record, source);
    const options ={style: 'percent', minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 6}
    const relativeValue = Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', options).format(absoluteValue)
    
    return record ? 
    <Typography component="span" variant="body2">
        {relativeValue}
    </Typography> : null;
}
```